# How to add "Leave a Comment" link or button at the bottom of each post in the "Latest Posts" block?

Tags: plugin-development, filters, hooks, block-editor

I have been digging around in WordPress developer resources to see if I can figure out how to add "Leave a Comment" link or button at the bottom of each post in the "Latest Posts" block.

I found the `render_block` and `render_block_core` hooks but I cannot figure out how to add the link or button to each rendered post. My thought is that this should be possible using the `$block['attrs']` attributes. I'm still pretty new to WP development and this problem I'm stuck with for some time now.

Any hints would be highly appreciated!